# MySQL: change column name currently named with a key word

Tags: mysql

I have a table "stats" in MySQL and one of the columns is named "AS".

Now I want to change its name, and I try to run

```
ALTER TABLE stats CHANGE COLUMN AS NEW_NAME varchar(5);
```

The error is

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS NEW_NAME varchar(5)'
```

I tried putting '' or "" around columns names but it didn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks:

```
ALTER TABLE stats CHANGE `COLUMN` AS `NEW_NAME` varchar(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use backticks, Using backticks permits you to use alternative characters.

Use below query:

```
ALTER TABLE stats CHANGE `COLUMN` AS `NEW_NAME` varchar(5);
```

Backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a MySQL reserved keyword, or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set (see below) It is often recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible, avoiding the quoting issue.

Hope it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE stats CHANGE COLUMN `AS` `NEW_NAME` varchar(5);
```